# Binary Images of Triangle Counts

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, sequence, binary

My challenges tend to be a little bit hard and unattractive. So here something easy and fun.

### Alcuin's sequence

[Alcuin's sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcuin%27s_sequence) `A(n)` is defined by counting triangles. `A(n)` is the number of triangles with integer sides and perimeter `n`. This sequence is called after Alcuin of York.

The first few elements of this sequence, starting with `n = 0` are:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 7, 5, 8, 7, 10, 8, ...
```

For instance `A(9) = 3`, because the only triangles with integer sides and perimeter `9` are `1 - 4 - 4`, `3 - 3 - 3` and `2 - 3 - 4`. You can see the 3 valid triangles down below.

[image: Triangles with integer sides and perimeter 9]

There are some quite interesting pattern in this sequence. For instance `A(2*k) = A(2*k - 3)`.

For more information, see [A005044](http://oeis.org/A005044) on OEIS.

### Challenge

But your challenge is about the binary representation of these numbers. If we convert each sequence number to it's binary representation, put them in column vectors and line them up, it creates a quite interesting binary picture.

In the following picture you can see the binary representation of the sequence numbers `A(0), A(1), ..., A(149)`. In the first column you can see the binary representation of `A(1)`, in the second column the representation of `A(1)`, and so on.

[image: Binary representation of Alcuin's sequence from n = 0 to 149]

You can see some sort of repeating pattern in this picture. It even looks kinda like fractals, if you look for instance at the image with the sequence numbers `A(600), A(601), ..., A(899)`.

[image: Binary representation of Alcuin's sequence from n = 600 to 899]

Your job is to generate such an image. Your function, your script will receive two integer `0 <= m < n`, and it has to generate the binary image of Alcuin's sequence `A(m), A(m+1), A(m+2), ..., A(n-2), A(n-1)`. So the input `0, 150` generates the first picture, the input `600, 900` the second picture.

You can use any popular graphics format you want. Let's say every format that can be converted to png using [image.online-convert.com](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png). Alternatively, you may display the image on screen. No leading white rows are allowed!

This is code-golf. So the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Eh, I was interested in doing this challenge until I got to the part about creating a binary image. It seems like an extraneous step. I don't feel like learning a library for image creation in Python, and I expect that if I did, there wouldn't be much to golf.

Comment: @xnor: Then use some simple image format like [PBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PBM_example).

Comment: Is it `white=1 and black=0` or the other way around?

Comment: @Maltysen `white=0 and black=1`. So the other way. `A(0)` produces a white column, `A(9)=3` produces a white column with 2 black pixel at the bottom.

Comment: Is `A(2*k) = A(2*k - 3)` a typo? Wouldn't that mean that the sequence would be periodic with period 3?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Nope, `k` has to be an integer. Therefore `A(6) = A(3)` but `A(6) != A(9)`. But be aware that this little fact has nothing to do with the challenge at all.

Comment: @Jakube Oh, I see. That makes sense.

Comment: Are you sure the first image is correct? It has `0,0,0,1,0,2` while the list at the beginning of the question says `0,0,0,1,0,1`.

Comment: @Maltysen Your right. Had a little bug in my own program. Replaced them with correct images now.

Comment: Should the "pixels" be 1 pixel sized and rectangular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## J (<s>52</s> 45 (Codepage 437))

This would be allowed (I think)

```
[:|:' █'{~[:#:[:([:<.48%~*:+24+6*]*2|])(}.i.)
```

#### Hex dump

(Nothing special really, the black square is DB<sub>16</sub> or 219<sub>10</sub> in codepage 437.)

```
0000: 5b 3a 7c 3a 27 20 db 27 7b 7e 5b 3a 23 3a 5b 3a   [:|:' .'{~[:#:[:
0010: 28 5b 3a 3c 2e 34 38 25 7e 2a 3a 2b 32 34 2b 36   ([:<.48%~*:+24+6
0020: 2a 5d 2a 32 7c 5d 29 28 7d 2e 69 2e 29            *]*2|])(}.i.)
```

#### Usage

This outputs as follows (The code tags mess it up by adding space between the lines):

```
   A=:[:|:' █'{~[:#:[:([:<.48%~*:+24+6*]*2|])(}.i.)
   0 A 100
                                                                             █ █████████████████████                                          
                                                     █ ██████████████████████ █              █ █████                          
                                     █ ██████████████ █          █ ██████████ █      █ ██████ █                   
                         █ ██████████ █      █ ██████ █    █ ████ █    █ ████ █  █ ██ █  █ ██ █  █ █  
                 █ ██████ █    █ ████ █  █ ██ █  █ ██ █  █  █  █  █  █  ██ ██ ██  ██  ██  ██  ██  ██
           █ ████ █  █ ██ █  █  █  █  ██  ██  ██  ██  ██  █  █  █  █ ██ █  █ ████ █                               
       █ ██ █  █  ██  ██  ██  █  █ ██ █                █ ██ █  █  ██  ██  ██  █  █ ██ █                                   
   █ ██ ██  ██ ██ █        █ ██ ██  ██ ██ █        █ ██ ██  ██ ██ █        █ ██ ██  ██ ██ █        █    
   2000 A 2100
████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████

████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
                                                                             █ █████████████████████
                             █ ██████████████████████████████████████████████ █
     █ ██████████████████████ █                      █ ██████████████████████ █
█████ █          █ ██████████ █          █ ██████████ █          █ ██████████ █          █ █████████
 ████ █    █ ████ █    █ ████ █    █ ████ █    █ ████ █    █ ████ █    █ ████ █    █ ████ █    █ ███
█  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █
██  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █ ██ ██ █
 █ ██ ██ ██ ██ ██ █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  ██ ██ ██ ██ ██  █  █
  ██ ██ ██  █  █  ██ ██ ██  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █ ██ ██ ██ █  █  █  █ ██ █  █ ██
 █ ██ █  █ ██ █  █ ██ █  █ ██ █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  █  ██ ██ ██  █  █  ██  ██ ██ ██  ██  ██  ██
  ██  ██  ██  ██  ██  ██  ██  ██ ██ ██  █  █  █  █  █  █ ██ █  █ ██ █  █ ████ █    █ ██████ █
█ █                        █ ████ █  █ ██ █  █  █  █  ██  ██  ██  ██  ██  █  █  █  █ ██ █  █ ████ █
 █ ██ █                █ ██ █  █  ██  ██  ██  █  █ ██ █                █ ██ █  █  ██  ██  ██  █  █ █
██  ██ ██ █        █ ██ ██  ██ ██ █        █ ██ ██  ██ ██ █        █ ██ ██  ██ ██ █        █ ██ ██
```

In the standard J console, there is no spacing between lines, so I call the rule 'Alternatively, you may display the image on screen.' (Nowhere did it say that this image had to be represented as a sensible image format internally)

EDIT: Jconsole (as opposed to JQT) uses codepage 437 as a default, and DOES render the rectangles correctly when using them from a string.

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica, <s>126</s> <s>122</s> <s>121</s> 89 bytes

```
Image[1-Thread@IntegerDigits[l=Round[(#+3#~Mod~2)^2/48]&/@Range@##,2,⌈2~Log~Max@l⌉]]&
```

This defines an unnamed function taking the two integers as parameters and displaying the image on screen. It plots each square as a single pixel, but if you like you can actually zoom in.

I'm now using an explicit formula given [in the OEIS article](http://oeis.org/A005044) (first one in the Mathematica section, thanks to David Carraher for pointing that out). It's also blazingly fast now.

Here is the indented code with a few comments:

```
Image[1-Thread@IntegerDigits[   (* 3. Convert each number to padded binary, transpose
                                      invert colours, and render as Image. *)
    l = Round[
      (#+3#~Mod~2)^2/48
    ] & /@ Range@##,            (* 1. Turn input into a range and get the Alcuin
                                      number for each element. *)
    2,
    ⌈2~Log~Max@l⌉               (* 2. Determine the maximum number of binary digits. *)
]] &
```

Here is the output for `0, 600`:

[image]

Comment: Just about the same size (because left and right ceiling must be spelled out): `Image[1 - 
   Thread@IntegerDigits[
     l = Round[If[EvenQ[#], #^2, (# + 3)^2]/48] & /@ Range@##, 
     2, \[LeftCeiling]2~Log~Max@l\[RightCeiling]]] &`

Comment: @DavidCarraher Thanks, I golfed it a bit further. :) (Should have checked the OEIS article.)

Answer (score 8):

### CJam (<strike>56 55</strike> 53 chars) / GolfScript (64 chars)

CJam:

```
"P1"q~,>{_1&3*+_*24+48/}%_:e>2b,\2_$#f+2fbz(,@@:~~]N*
```

GolfScript:

```
"P1"\~,>{.1&3*+.*24+48/}%.$-1=2base,\{2.$?+2base}%zip(,@@{~}/]n*
```

Both produce output in NetPBM format, and they're essentially ports of each other.

#### Dissection

```
CJam                 GolfScript           Explanation

"P1"                 "P1"\                NetPBM header
q~,>                 ~,>                  Create array [m .. n-1]
{_1&3*+_*24+48/}%    {.1&3*+.*24+48/}%    Map the sequence calculation
_:e>2b,\             .$-1=2base,\         Compute image height H as highest bit
                                          in largest number in sequence
2_$#f+2fb            {2.$?+2base}%        Map sequence to bits, ensuring that
                                          each gives H bits by adding 2^H
z(,@@                zip(,@@              Transpose and pull off dummy row to use
                                          its length as the "width" in the header
:~~                  {~}/                 Flatten double array and dump on stack
]N*                  ]n*                  Separate everything with whitespace
```

Thanks to [Optimizer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31414/optimizer) for CJam 56 -> 53.

Comment: Any reason you don't have "P1" at the beginning and thus save 1 byte by avoiding the `\` ?

Comment: @Optimizer, too used to thinking in GS.

Comment: Not quite: the height needs to appear in the output. But there's still a saving to be made with the map shortening.

Comment: 51: `'PoXq~{_1&3*+_*24+48/}%>_:e>2b,\2_$#f+2fbz(,@@]e_N*`

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth - <strike>101</strike> <strike>60</strike> 59

Outputs a `.pbm`. Can likely be golfed more.

```
Km.B/++24*dd**6%d2d48rvzQJCm+*\0-eSmlkKlddK"P1"lhJlJjbmjbdJ
```

<strike>Highly ungolfed because I will be translating to Pyth.</strike>

<strike>Explanation coming next. Right now look at the equivalent Python code.</strike>

It uses the OEIS algorithm to calculate the sequence and then it converts to binary, pads the numbers, does a matrix rotation, and formats it into a `pbm` image. Since I'm not using brute force, it is incredibly fast.

```
         K=
 m          rvzQ      Map from eval input to eval input
  .B                  Binary rep
   /      48          Divided by 48
    ++                Triple sum      
     24               Of 24,
     *dd              Square of d
     **               Triple product
      6               6
      %d2             Modulo d%2
      d               Var d
J                     Set J=
 C                    Matrix rotation from columns of row to rows of columns
  m           K       Map K (This does padding)
   +                  String concat
    *                 String repeat
     \0               "0"
     -     ld         Subtract the length of the column from
      eS              The max
       mlkK           Of all the column lengths
    d                 The column
"P1"                  Print header "P1"
l                     Length of
 hJ                   First row
lJ                    Number of columns
jb                    Join by linebreaks
 m  J                 Map on to J
  jb                  Joined columns by linb
   d
```

Here is the `600,900` example:

[image: 600 - 900]

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Km.B%2F%2B%2B24*dd**6%25d2d48rvzQJCm%2B*%5C0-eSmlkKlddK%22P1%22lhJlJjbmj%5C%20dJ&input=600%0A900).

Answer (score 4):

## R - <s>127</s> 125

I'm not sure if this complies with the rules totally.  It doesn't output an image to a file, but it does create a raster and plot it to an output device.

I found the same formula as Martin, but [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlcuinsSequence.html).

It uses an unnamed function.

```
require(raster);function(m,n)plot(raster(mapply(function(n)rev(as.integer(intToBits(round((n+n%%2*3)^2/48)))),m:n),0,n,0,32))
```

Run as follows

```
require(raster);(function(m,n)plot(raster(mapply(function(n)rev(as.integer(intToBits(round((n+n%%2*3)^2/48)))),m:n),0,n,0,32)))(0,600)
```

Produces the following plot

[image]

Comment: You can drop 7 bytes by not attaching `raster` to the namespace, since `raster()` is the only thing in there specific to that package. Instead just do `raster::raster(...)`.

Comment: @AlexA. Thanks, will make that edit

Comment: @AlexA. Unfortunately I just tried it and it errors out for me.  I suspect that it's because raster requires sp as well.  I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: Bummer. Sorry to have led you astray.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 <s>+ PIL</s>, <s>255</s> 184

My first version used PIL in order to show an image :

```
i,R,B=input,range,lambda x:bin((x*x+6*x*(x%2)+24)/48)[2:]
def F(k,v):i.load()[k]=v
a,b=i(),i();h=len(B(b));from PIL import Image;i=Image.new('P',(b-a,h))
[F((x-a,y),int(B(x).zfill(h)[y])) for x in R(a,b) for y in R(h)]
i.putpalette([255]*3+[0]*3)
i.show()
```

The new version just produces a b&w PPM image on stdout :

```
i,R,B=input,range,lambda x:bin((x*x+6*x*(x%2)+24)/48)[2:]
def p(s):print s
a,b=i(),i();h=len(B(b));p('P1 %i %i'%(b-a,h))
[p(' '.join([B(x).zfill(h)[y] for x in R(a,b)])) for y in R(h)]
```

Comment: Some character saves for the PPM version: You don't need a space before `for`. You can avoid parens around `x%2` by changing the order to `x%2*...`. It's shorter not to define print as a function and just use two nested `for` loops, using `print ...,` to avoid newlines and a blank `print` to start a new line. A trick to force binary expansions to have length `h` without `zfill` is to add `2**h`, then extract the last `h` digits.

Answer (score 2):

### JAVASCRIPT - 291

Code:

```
(function(a,b,c){c.width=b;t=c.getContext('2d');t.strokeStyle='black';for(i=a;i<=b;i++){g=(Math.floor(((i*i)+6*i*(i%2)+24)/48)>>>0).toString(2);l=g.length;for(j=0;j<l;j++){if(g[l-1-j]=='1'){t.rect(i-a,j,1,1);t.fill();}}}document.body.appendChild(c);})(0,300,document.createElement('canvas'))
```

Explanation:

```
(function (a, b, c) {
    //setting canvas width
    c.width = b;
    //get context 2d of canvas
    t = c.getContext('2d');
    //setting storke style.
    t.strokeStyle = 'black';
    //looping from a to b
    for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        //calculating A(i) and converting it to a binary string
        g = (Math.floor(((i * i) + 6 * i * (i % 2) + 24) / 48) >>> 0).toString(2);
        //looping through that string
        for (j = 0; j < g.length; j++) {
            //since canvas is upside down and the first digit is actually the last digit:
            if (g[g.length - 1 - j] == '1') {
                //we create the 1 by 1 rect
                t.rect(i - a, j, 1, 1);
                //we draw the rect
                t.fill();
            }
        }
    }
    //we append everything to the body
    document.body.appendChild(c);
    //parameters are put here
})(0, 300, document.createElement('canvas'))
```

Result:

Yes the result is upside down, but that's because `0,0` on a `js canvas` is top left. :3
[image: Alquin's sequence]

Demo:

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/8ms76eLb/60/)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>26 25</s></sup> 24 bytes

```apl
' ⎕'[⊤⌊12÷⍨6+×⍨⊥⊖0 2⊤…⎕]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@qysABdSjH3UtedTTZWh0ePuj3hVm2oenA6lHXUsfdU0zUDACSTYsA6qL/Q/U8z@Ny9DIQMEAAA)

Takes the inputs in reverse(-1 byte).

-1 byte from Bubbler(`.5+12÷⍨ → 12÷⍨6+`)

Generates the sequence in the same way as the existing J solution, except Bubbler shortened it with some math [explained here.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56022229#56022229)

Uses '⎕' as the display character. If '█' is required, then it becomes 27 bytes(does look nicer with it).

### Explanation

```apl
' ⎕'[⊤⌊12÷⍨6+×⍨⊥⊖0 2⊤…⎕]
                      ⎕  take the second and first inputs
                     …   create an inclusive range between them
                 0 2⊤    encode into parts of 0 & 2
                ⊖        reverse the columns
               ⊥         decode from base 2
                         (this calculates (n+3×(n%2))/2)
             ×⍨          square that
      ⌊12÷⍨6+            divide by 12, round to the nearest integer               
     ⊤                   encode in base 2
                         (this gives a binary matrix witht the required graph)
' ⎕'[                  ] convert 0s to ' ' and 1s to '⎕'
```

Comment: `.5+12÷⍨ → 12÷⍨6+`